# What happens when we make an array defined using characters instead of integers in C?

Tags: arrays, c

This is a code I have used to define an array:

```
int characters[126];
```

following which I wanted to get a record of the frequencies of all the characters recorded for which I used the while loop in this format:

```
while((a=getchar())!=EOF){
    characters[a]=characters[a]+1;
}
```

Then using a for loop I print the values of integers in the array.

How exactly is this working?

Does C assign a specific number for letters ie. a,b,c, etc in the array?

Comment: characters are also integral types. They all have a numeric representation (which you can easily check out yourself)

Comment: On top of what have been said, the return type of `getchar()` is `int`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but be careful with the (little) code you show: First of all the default values of the array `characters` depend on where you defined the array or if it was defined using `static`. If it was defined as a local non-static variable, then it will be *uninitialized* and each element will have an *indeterminate* value. Secondly, remember that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**, which is *very* crucial for the comparison to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Dr.Nykterstein, Note: `characters[a]` will be a problem when `a` (often 8-bt) is outside the range [0-125].

Comment: Also, considering that the most common character encoding scheme ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) is *seven* bits, it will have values from `0` to **`127`** (inclusive). So you need an array of `128` elements to be able to handle all ASCII values. And depending on your system the `getchar` function might actually return values *outside* of that range (values from `0` to `255`) which could lead you to go way out of bounds of your array. You need to add some checks for that case.

Comment: Dr.Nykterstein, "Does C assign a specific number for letters ie. a,b,c, etc in the array?" --> Yes.

Comment: `array['a'] = 5` is perfectly fine, if thats what you mean.

Comment: As an experiment, try e.g. `printf("%d\n", 'a');` and see what happens.

Comment: Just beware that if `a` is defined as `char` and `char` is signed in your implementation, you may invoke Undefined Behaviour with `characters[a]` (for example `characters[-42]`).

Comment: @UnholySheep "characters are also integral types" Could that statement lead someone to accidentally perceive a multi-byte character as an instance of an integral type? Would it be more accurate to say "char is an integral type"?

Comment: *What happens when we make an array defined using characters instead of integers in C?* As you've now learned, characters *are* integers in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when we make an array defined using characters instead of integers in C?

Let's be sure we are clear: you are using integer values returned by `getchar()` as indexes into your array.  This is not *defining* the array, it is just *accessing* its elements.

> Does C assign a specific number for letters ie. a,b,c, etc in the array?

There are no letters in the array.  There are `int`s.  However, yes, the characters read by `getchar()` are encoded as integer values, so they are, in principle, suitable array indexes.  Thus, this line ...

> ```
>     characters[a]=characters[a]+1;
> ```

... reads the `int` value then stored at index `a` in array `characters`, adds 1 to it, and then assigns the result back to element `a` of the array, *provided that* the value of `a` is a valid index into the array.

More generally, it is important to understand that although one of its major uses is to represent characters, type `char` is an *integer* type.  Its values are numbers.  The mapping from characters to numbers is implementation and context dependent, but it is common enough for the mapping to be consistent with the ASCII code that you will often see programs that assume such a mapping.

Indeed, your code makes exactly such an assumption (and others) by allowing only for character codes less than 126.

You should also be aware that if your `characters` array is declared inside a function then it is not initialized.  The code depends on all elements to be initially to zero.  I would recommend this declaration instead:

```
int characters[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
```

That upper bound will be sufficient for all the non-`EOF` values returned by `getchar()`, and the explicit zero-initialization will ensure the needed initial values regardless of where the array is declared.

Comment: Aside to novices:  be sure to use `int` to receive the `getchar()` as in `int ch; ... ch = getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized the charecter set that can function as an input for getchar() is part of the ASCII table and comes under an int. I used the code following to find that out:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
    int a[128];
    a['b']=4;
    printf("%d",a[98]); //it is 98 as according to the table 'b' is assigned the value of 98
  }
```

following which executing this code i get the output of 4.
I am really new to coding so feel free to correct me.

Comment: `98 == 'b'` is a reasonable _assumption_,  still an assumption, although _very_ common, not a specification.

Comment: When you are using characters this way, make the array size `UCHAR_MAX+1` to allow for the user to enter any character in the character set, and use `unsigned char` or otherwise be careful to index the array with non-negative values. (The `char` type may be signed.) Also, ASCII is common, but it is not required by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "use unsigned char or otherwise be careful to index " is OK to index, yet not for OP's first step of `(a=getchar())!=EOF`.  Recommend `int a` to well test the `EOF` condition and then in the loop have a non-negative for array indexing.

Comment: If you do not understand `UCHAR_MAX`, just use 256 instead of 128 for the array length as 8-bit bytes have values in the range 0..255. Some exotic platforms have larger bytes, which is why the maximum byte value is defined as `UCHAR_MAX` in `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Character values are represented using some kind of integer encoding - [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (very common), [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (mostly IBM mainframes), [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (backward-compatible to ASCII), etc.

The character value `'a'` maps to some integer value - `97` in ASCII and UTF-8, `129` in EBCDIC.  So yes, you can use a character value to index into an array - `arr['a']++` would be equivalent to `arr[97]++` if you were using ASCII or UTF-8.

The C language does not dictate this - it's determined by the underlying platform.

Comment: It would be logical to advise the use `int characters[256];` instead of 126.